# AngularJs cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have an authenticationService which contains this function:

```
//this.userApi = Restangular.service('api/sessions');

login(user) {
    let that = this;

    this.userApi.post(user).then(function(user) {
        that.session.create(user.sessionId, user.userId, user.username);
        return user;
    });
}
```

And in my controller:

```
login() {
    this.authService
        .login(that.user)
        .then(function(user) {
            $scope.setCurrentUser(user);

        },
        function(result) {
            console.log('fail', result.status);
        });
}
```

I don't understand why I get 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' on this line: `that.authService.login(that.user).then(function (user) ...`

Comment: that.authService.login is clearly returning undefined. (your code doesn't make it return anything)

Comment: It doesn't return undefined according to my debugger.

Comment: read the error message again. "cannot read property 'then' of undefined" pointing at the line `that.authService.login().then(` so obviously it is returning undefined, because `then` is not defined on `undefined`.

Comment: Oh it is undefined. But i don't understand why ?

Comment: Because you didn't return anything from `login(user) {` in your first snippet. If you return nothing in that case, `undefined` is returned.

Comment: ooh now I see my error. I forgot to put return before this.userApi.post(user)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first snippet, you need to return the promise so that you can continue the chain in your other snippet.

```
//this.userApi = Restangular.service('api/sessions');

login(user) {
    let that = this;

    return this.userApi.post(user).then(function(user) {
        that.session.create(user.sessionId, user.userId, user.username);
        return user;
    });
}
```

Comment: that was close kevin :D you beat me by 3 seconds I will upvote your answer

Comment: anyway great answer ;)

Comment: Thank you guys, I accepted this answer because i found it by his helpfull comments.

Answer (score 4):

You should try this :

```
//this.userApi = Restangular.service('api/sessions');

login(user) {
    let that = this;

   return this.userApi.post(user).then(function(user) {
        that.session.create(user.sessionId, user.userId, user.username);
        return user;
    });
}
```